# ASP.net Using Eval pass a comma separated string as Argument

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an Eval function in my aspx as below.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick='<%# "javascript:MyJSFunction(" + Eval("ObjectIdList") + ");return false;" %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

The ObjectIdList is a list comma seperated ids as below from the server end

234,333,444,555

My javascript is as below

```
function MyJSFunction(Ids){
    alert(Ids)
}
```

My javascript function only displays the first id of 234. I have tried putting single quotes as below but I get an error 'Server tag is not well formed'

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick='<%# "javascript:MyJSFunction('" + Eval("ObjectIdList") + "');return false;" %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Please Help

Comment: Only put the `Eval(...)` part in `<%# %>` and then fix the quotes.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the single javascript quotes in the string with `&#39;`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
    OnClientClick='<%# "javascript:MyJSFunction(&#39;" + Eval("ObjectIdList") + "&#39;);return false;" %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```